# When I run the program it asks for my input multiple times even after I've entered it once already

Tags: python, input

When I run the program it asks for my input multiple times even after I've entered it once already.

```
Peeps = {"Juan":244, "Jayne":433, "Susan":751}
```

Asks the user to input a name which is the key to a value, which it returns

```
for i in Peeps:
    if i == input("Type in a name: "):
        print("The amount", [i], "owes is:", "$" + str(Peeps[i]))
        break
    else:
        print("Sorry that name does not exist, please enter a new name.")
```

Comment: Sorry the formatting is bad, still new to the site but the comment has a piece of the code. (the for loop "for i in Peeps:")

Comment: you're calling `input` inside a loop, so it asks you every time. If you don't want that, move the `input` call outside the loop and save the value to a variable you can then compare with in your loop

Comment: I see, so I should avoid calling an input when doing loops?

Comment: `input` will ask for a new value EVERY time it is called. So in this case, you wanted only one value, so you shouldn't have called it in a loop.

There is no general rule to not call `input` in a loop or anything, sometimes you might even want to do that. it just wasn't what you wanted in this particular case.

Comment: Oh, I can see what I was doing wrong now. I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 2):

You need to ask the user input first instead of comparing the user input directly to the key.

Answer (score 1):

You do not want to do it like that. Take a look at the following instead:

```
Peeps = {"Juan":244, "Jayne":433, "Susan":751}
name = input("Type in a name: ")
if name in Peeps:
    print("The amount", name, "owes is:", "$" + str(Peeps[name]))
else:
    print("Sorry that name does not exist, please enter a new name.")
```

You do not have to loop through your `dict` and check the user input against each value individually (plus you are forcing the user to update\re-enter his input continuously).

Just receive it once and process it.

---

If you want to keep the loop running to allow for multiple queries, use `while` like so:

```
Peeps = {"Juan": 244, "Jayne": 433, "Susan": 751}
name = input("Type in a name or leave blank to exit: ")
while name:
    if name in Peeps:
        print("The amount", name, "owes is:", "$" + str(Peeps[name]))
    else:
        print("Sorry that name does not exist, please enter a new name.")
    name = input("Type in a name or leave blank to exit: ")
```

Comment: I am adding comments now.

Comment: This is actually really helpful, thank you Ev. Kounis I really appreciate the help!